# Inconsistency (?) in Firebase docs for creating apps

Tags: javascript, firebase

I used the Firebase CLI to create my app, I used `firebase init` and it created an index and whatever for me with all of these scripts in the head:

```
<!-- update the version number as needed -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.8.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.8.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.8.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.8.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/7.8.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

However, when I go onto the Firebase console I see that I am supposed to do this in the `body` of my HTML file before I call any firebase functions:

```
  // Set the configuration for your app
  // TODO: Replace with your app's config object
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '<your-api-key>',
    authDomain: '<your-auth-domain>',
    databaseURL: '<your-database-url>',
    storageBucket: '<your-storage-bucket-url>'
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  // Get a reference to the storage service, which is used to create references in your storage bucket
  var storage = firebase.storage();
```

I have this *nowhere* in my code yet I can still access `firebase.firestore.Firestore` and get to my database no issue. I am having the issue where I cannot access `firebase.storage.Storage`. I get an error `Firebase App named '[DEFAULT'] already exists` or `does not exist`, whether or not I do the `initializeApp` step.

I assume the CLI did some setup that I cannot seem to find... I checked the `.firebaserc` and `firebase.json` file but I cannot see where I put the information I would otherwise put in the `firebaseConfig` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration block is automatically generated for you when you include:

```
<script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

If you open the file at that location, you'll see it looks very similar to the `firebaseConfig` block in the documentation.

The `/__/firebase/init.js` only works on Firebase Hosting, and not on other hosting providers, which is why you'll see the more generic Firebase documentation have the explicitly `firebaseConfig` block, while the CLI (which knows you're using Firebase Hosting) generates the `/__/firebase/init.js` script include.

Also see the Firebase documentation on this [auto configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#sdk_auto-configuration).

Comment: Maybe this next part should go in a separate question, but how can I then setup Firebase Cloud Storage? If I let `/__/firebase/init.js` take care of the initialization, I still cannot call `firebase.storage()`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't call `firebase.storage()`. Its configuration data should be in the block in `init.js`. If you're having problems getting that to work, open a new question with the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to include the code from `init.js`, just in case something is going wrong here.

Comment: Thank you for your help and expertise. I am going to accept it, but there was a timer that needed to count down until I could. I will do some more digging for storage issue.